# Uploaded images that are saved to file system cannot be accessed by website visitors (404)

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload, http-status-code-404

So I'm using ASP.Net's FileUpload control to upload and save images to the file system in my web application.  The images were originally not being allowed to save because IIS didn't have access to the folder, which was remedied by right-clicking the folder, going to the security tab, selecting the IIS user and authorizing Write and Modify.

The website user can now upload an image and said image is saved successfully in the folder.  The same website also displays the same images but the server is responding with a 404 (Not Found) error whenever the browser requests the image.  I can remote desktop into the server, navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer, right-click the uploaded images, and open them in a browser.  The images are then displayed perfectly.

So they're only not accessible via an outside website visitor.

I'm guessing I need to make some change to permissions or settings in IIS, but the only thing I've thought of to check is that the IIS user has Read permissions in that folder, which it indeed does.

Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: If your user can write to the folder, how come they couldn't read from it? - check where the Url is pointing to if it's correct -e.g. copy the url and paste in the browser

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why the server is returning a 404.  The URL is correct, as the same URL works perfectly fine when I test the site locally, running localhost.  (obviously the domain is different, but everything else is the same)

Comment: the best way to be sure is open the source of your html, copy the url and paste in the browser. And also check the extension of the file is correct

Comment: Where is the code that you write and read them ?

Comment: codingbiz, thanks man.  So, it was a silly thing, of course.  I wasn't saving the files with an extension. Now I know this is a stupid thing to be doing, but I was going to fix it just as soon as I got it loaded on the server. :D  For some reason the localhost server was A-Okay with serving up files w/o a file extension, but IIS, naturally, is not.  Anyway, saving the files with the extension solves the problem.  Thanks again.  If you make an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.